# "OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer" altough checked for it

Tags: python, infinity

I get the error

> OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

from this code:

```
if not math.isinf(data['occurrence'][0][key]):
                   df.set_value(df.date == key, name, data['occurrence'][0][key])
```

How come the `set_value` part gets executed anyway? How to fix this?

**EDIT**:

Full Stack Trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "aggregateData.py", line 27,
>   in 
>       df.set_value(df.date == key, name, data['occurrence'][0][key]) #update df   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line
>   1690, in set_value
>       self.loc[index, col] = value   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line
>   114, in **setitem**
>       indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line
>   106, in _get_setitem_indexer
>       return self._convert_tuple(key, is_setter=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line
>   155, in _convert_tuple
>       idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i, is_setter=is_setter)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py",
>   line 1025, in _convert_to_indexer
>       obj = self._convert_scalar_indexer(obj, axis)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line
>   163, in _convert_scalar_indexer
>       return ax._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=self.name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line
>   806, in _convert_scalar_indexer
>       return to_int()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line
>   787, in to_int
>       ikey = int(key) OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Comment: What does `print(data['occurrence'][0][key])` give?

Comment: Based on the snippet you gave I agree that it seems somewhat mysterious. `try`...`except` would be a simple work-around, although it would clearly be preferable to understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: Try poking around with the debugger: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.  Figure out which part is throwing the error instead of posting a big blob of code.  Posting the full stack trace doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Are you sure that it is `df.set_value()` which is throwing the error? Perhaps Python throws the error when it tries to evaluate `data['occurrence'][0][key]` in order to feed it into `math.isinf()`

Comment: `print(data['occurrence'][0][key])` gives me a '1'

Answer (score 0):

The end of the stack trace

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 787, in to_int ikey = int(key) OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

strongly suggests that it is the *key* that can't be converted to an integer (especially given the fact that `data['occurrence'][0][key]` seems to be 1. What does `print key` print?